# Mongoose text index on nested schema field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following schema:

```
const Schema = ({
  metadata: {
    title: String,
    ...
  },
  ...

});
```

and I'm looking to create a a text index on `metadata.title`.  I can create a text index successfully on any first level property, but I'm running into trouble with the nested title.

I've tried the following code, to no avail.  Is my syntax wrong?  I've had no luck with docs...

```
Schema.index({ 'metadata.title': 'text' });
```

Searching:

```
Schema
  .find(
    { $text : { $search : req.params.query } },
    { score : { $meta: "textScore" } })
```

Comment: Started bounty- but turns out that current answer solves the problem.  Will award bounty there.

Comment: Your original attempt of `Schema.index({ 'metadata.title': 'text' });` is the right way to do this and works just fine when I try it. The currently accepted answer will just create a traditional index, not a text index. Your use of `Schema` for your schema (and your model) is a bit confusing as you should really keep that identifier name as the `Schema` constructor.

Comment: Yeah, it's called something different in my code, I just used Schema here as a placeholder... sorry.  And yes, actually my original attempt works as you said.... who do I award the bounty to?

Comment: I guess you'll just need to let the bounty expire. But you should really post your own answer and accept that, or at least remove the check mark from the currently accepted answer as that one is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out what I had originally was correct, as pointed out by @JohnnyHK.  I must have had some other error that caused the index to not work...

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Schema = ({
  metadata: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      index: true
      }
    ...
  },
  ...

});
```

Comment: Hm... mongoose seems to throw an error when I do this.  `TypeError: Undefined type undefined at metadata.index`

Comment: Sorry. Fixed my answer.

Comment: Hm.  Still doesn't work, at least not with my search.  I added how I'm searching, can you make sure it still matches up?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to recreate the index with the new parameters
or try to drop and recreate the collection